# AWS S3 | Allow grantee to ONLY download objects from the bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It is possible to allow grantee to ONLY download objects from the AWS S3 bucket ? They should not be able to upload any documents in the bucket. If it is possible what bucket permissions should we assign to grantee ? I tried searching this over the web but couldn't find any relevant links.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the read only permissions to the grantee to your bucket.

Comment: The relevant IAM action is s3:GetObject

Answer (score 1):

You can use following URL to generate the required policy.

https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Select Type of Policy : **S3 Bucket Policy**

Effect: Check **Allow**

Principal: *  (Which means for every one)

**Actions:** GetObject

**Amazon Resource Name (ARN):** ARN should follow the following format: arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/<key_name>.
Use a comma to separate multiple values.

Press Add statement and in step 3 you will be able to generate required policy.

Below is a sample policy.

```
{
  "Id": "PolicyID",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1610823452352355758",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::sample-resource-name/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```